# Chromebook dual boot issue

Tags: dual-boot, chromebook, chromeos

I have my Acer C710 Chromebook duel-booted with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and the command line to switch the boot order from Chrome-OS to Ubuntu is not having any effect I will enter the command in the Chrome-OS development console and then reboot it and it enters Chrome OS again. I have tried everything I can to get it to boot into Ubuntu and it is not working
the command I am entering is, `sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 5 -S 1 /dev/sda`. I have not had any issues with this in the past and was wondering what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If using crouton, While in develope mode, simply hold down Ctrl, Alt, Shift and press the forward, or backwards key to switch into the alternate OS.

For Chrbuntu, I'm not exactly sure, i can find out if that is what you have used to install it.